# In-memory cache implementation revisited

Tags: c#, multithreading, cache

As a follow-up on [my earlier question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38619/in-memory-cache-implementation), here is the new implementation. The major change is now that the base class just deals in `ICacheValue` values which are implemented by the derived classes and generated through implementation of a factory method.

Unfortunately requires some casting in the derived classes but I don't think there is a way around it in C#.

Looking for general review, best practices, design improvements, hidden bugs etc.

**Cache base class**

It's now abstract and requires the implementation of the `CreateCacheValue` factory method. It only deals with the basic read/write access of items. All public methods are protected by a lock which call internal unlocked methods which are all virtual so they can get overwritten by the derived cache implementations.

```
public abstract class Cache<TKey, TValue>
{
    protected interface ICacheValue
    {
        TValue Value { get; set; }
    }

    protected readonly Dictionary<TKey, ICacheValue> _ValueCache = new Dictionary<TKey, ICacheValue>();
    protected object SyncRoot = new object();

    protected abstract ICacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value);
    protected abstract void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, ICacheValue cacheValue);
    protected abstract void CacheValueInvalidated(ICacheValue cacheValue);

    public virtual int Count
    {
        get { return _ValueCache.Count; }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        ICacheValue v;
        value = default(TValue);

        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            v = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
            if (v != null)
            {
                value = v.Value;
                UpdateElementAccess(key, v);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected virtual ICacheValue GetCacheValueUnlocked(TKey key)
    {
        ICacheValue v;
        return _ValueCache.TryGetValue(key, out v) ? v : null;
    }

    public void SetValue(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            SetValueUnlocked(key, value);
        }
    }

    protected virtual ICacheValue SetValueUnlocked(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        ICacheValue cacheValue = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
        if (cacheValue == null)
        {
            cacheValue = CreateCacheValue(value);
            _ValueCache[key] = cacheValue;
        }
        else
        {
            cacheValue.Value = value;
        }
        UpdateElementAccess(key, cacheValue);
        return cacheValue;
    }

    public void Invalidate(TKey key)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            InvalidateUnlocked(key);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void InvalidateUnlocked(TKey key)
    {
        var value = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
        if (value != null)
        {
            _ValueCache.Remove(key);
            CacheValueInvalidated(value);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Flush()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            FlushUnlocked();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void FlushUnlocked()
    {
        _ValueCache.Clear();
    }

    public List<TKey> GetKeys()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            return new List<TKey>(_ValueCache.Keys);
        }
    }
}
```

**Size limited cache**

Implements an LRU strategy. Items are invalidated on each cache access (read and write) if required.

```
public class SizeLimitedCache<TKey, TValue> : Cache<TKey, TValue>
{
    protected sealed class CacheValue : ICacheValue
    {
        public CacheValue(TValue value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>> IndexRef { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>> _IndexList = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>>();

    public int MaxSize { get; set; }

    public SizeLimitedCache(int maxSize)
    {
        MaxSize = maxSize;
    }

    protected override void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, ICacheValue cacheValue)
    {
        var value = (CacheValue)cacheValue;
        // put element at front of the index list
        // remove first if already present in list, create new otherwise
        var idxRef = value.IndexRef;
        if (idxRef != null)
        {
            _IndexList.Remove(idxRef);
        }
        else
        {
            idxRef = new LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>>(new KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>(key, value));
            value.IndexRef = idxRef;
        }
        _IndexList.AddFirst(idxRef);

        // remove all entries from end of list until max size is satisfied
        while (_IndexList.Count > MaxSize)
        {
            InvalidateUnlocked(_IndexList.Last.Value.Key);
        }
    }

    protected sealed override ICacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value)
    {
        return new CacheValue(value);
    }

    protected override void CacheValueInvalidated(ICacheValue cacheValue)
    {
        _IndexList.Remove(((CacheValue)cacheValue).IndexRef);
    }

    protected override void FlushUnlocked()
    {
        base.FlushUnlocked();
        _IndexList.Clear();
    }
}
```

**Time limited cache**

Regularly expires items from the cache. I'm not totally happy with this implementation because technically it makes all operations `O(n)` due to the expiry timer locking the cache when expiring items. Should probably be based on a similar idea as the size limited cache by checking from the end of the list for expired items (just time based rather than size based).

```
public class TimeLimitedCache<TKey, TValue> : Cache<TKey, TValue>, IDisposable
{
    protected sealed class CacheValue : ICacheValue
    {
        public CacheValue(TValue value)
        {
            Value = value;
            LastAccess = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public TValue Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastAccess { get; set; }
    }

    private DateTime _LastCacheAccess = DateTime.MinValue;

    public TimeSpan MaxEntryAge { get; set; }

    private TimeSpan _ExpiryInterval;
    public TimeSpan ExpiryInterval
    {
        get { return _ExpiryInterval; }
        set
        {
            _ExpiryInterval = value;
            DisposeTimer();
            _ExpiryTimer = new Timer(o => Expire(), null, value, value);
        }
    }

    private const int DefaultExpiryIntervalSec = 600;
    private System.Threading.Timer _ExpiryTimer;
    private int _ExpiryIsRunning = 0;

    public TimeLimitedCache(TimeSpan maxEntryAge)
        : this(maxEntryAge, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(DefaultExpiryIntervalSec))
    {
    }

    public TimeLimitedCache(TimeSpan maxEntryAge, TimeSpan expiryInterval)
    {
        MaxEntryAge = maxEntryAge;
        ExpiryInterval = expiryInterval;
    }

    private void Expire()
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _ExpiryIsRunning, 1, 0) == 1)
        {
            // expiry is still running
            return;
        }
        // paranoia
        try 
        {
            lock (SyncRoot)
            {
                var maxAge = MaxEntryAge;
                var toExpire = _ValueCache.Where(x => ((CacheValue)x.Value).LastAccess + maxAge < _LastCacheAccess).Select(x => x.Key).ToList();
                toExpire.ForEach(InvalidateUnlocked);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _ExpiryIsRunning = 0;
        }
    }

    protected override void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, ICacheValue cacheValue)
    {
        _LastCacheAccess = DateTime.Now;
        ((CacheValue)cacheValue).LastAccess = DateTime.Now;
    }

    protected sealed override ICacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value)
    {
        return new CacheValue(value);
    }

    protected override void CacheValueInvalidated(ICacheValue cacheValue)
    {
    }

    private void DisposeTimer()
    {
        if (_ExpiryTimer != null)
        {
            _ExpiryTimer.Change(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1), TimeSpan.Zero);
            _ExpiryTimer.Dispose();
            _ExpiryTimer = null;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            DisposeTimer();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Unfortunately requires some casting in the derived classes but I don't think there is a way around it in C#.

There is a way around that.

Define a 3rd template parameter to specify the type of cache value; use a `where` constraint on the 3rd parameter; and change the interface from protected to public (so that you can use it in the definition of the public Cache class):

```
public abstract class Cache<TKey, TValue, TCacheValue>
    where TCacheValue : class, Cache<TKey, TValue, TCacheValue>.ICacheValue
{
    public interface ICacheValue
    {
        TValue Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Use the specific TCacheValue type instead of ICacheValue throughout the implementation of the Cache class:

```
    protected readonly Dictionary<TKey, TCacheValue> _ValueCache = new Dictionary<TKey, TCacheValue>();
    protected object SyncRoot = new object();

    protected abstract TCacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value);
    protected abstract void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, TCacheValue cacheValue);
    protected abstract void CacheValueInvalidated(TCacheValue cacheValue);

    public virtual int Count
    {
        get { return _ValueCache.Count; }
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        TCacheValue v;
        value = default(TValue);

        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            v = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
            if (v != null)
            {
                value = v.Value;
                UpdateElementAccess(key, v);
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected virtual TCacheValue GetCacheValueUnlocked(TKey key)
    {
        TCacheValue v;
        return _ValueCache.TryGetValue(key, out v) ? v : null;
    }

    public void SetValue(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            SetValueUnlocked(key, value);
        }
    }

    protected virtual TCacheValue SetValueUnlocked(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        TCacheValue cacheValue = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
        if (cacheValue == null)
        {
            cacheValue = CreateCacheValue(value);
            _ValueCache[key] = cacheValue;
        }
        else
        {
            cacheValue.Value = value;
        }
        UpdateElementAccess(key, cacheValue);
        return cacheValue;
    }

    public void Invalidate(TKey key)
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            InvalidateUnlocked(key);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void InvalidateUnlocked(TKey key)
    {
        var value = GetCacheValueUnlocked(key);
        if (value != null)
        {
            _ValueCache.Remove(key);
            CacheValueInvalidated(value);
        }
    }

    public virtual void Flush()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            FlushUnlocked();
        }
    }

    protected virtual void FlushUnlocked()
    {
        _ValueCache.Clear();
    }

    public List<TKey> GetKeys()
    {
        lock (SyncRoot)
        {
            return new List<TKey>(_ValueCache.Keys);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can specify a subclass as follows, without using down-casts in the implementation, specifying Cache in the methods' signatures instead of ICache:

```
public class SizeLimitedCache<TKey, TValue> : Cache<TKey, TValue, SizeLimitedCache<TKey, TValue>.CacheValue>
{
    public sealed class CacheValue : ICacheValue
    {
        public CacheValue(TValue value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>> IndexRef { get; set; }
        public TValue Value { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>> _IndexList = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>>();

    public int MaxSize { get; set; }

    public SizeLimitedCache(int maxSize)
    {
        MaxSize = maxSize;
    }

    protected override void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, CacheValue cacheValue)
    {
        var value = cacheValue;
        // put element at front of the index list
        // remove first if already present in list, create new otherwise
        var idxRef = value.IndexRef;
        if (idxRef != null)
        {
            _IndexList.Remove(idxRef);
        }
        else
        {
            idxRef = new LinkedListNode<KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>>(new KeyValuePair<TKey, CacheValue>(key, value));
            value.IndexRef = idxRef;
        }
        _IndexList.AddFirst(idxRef);

        // remove all entries from end of list until max size is satisfied
        while (_IndexList.Count > MaxSize)
        {
            InvalidateUnlocked(_IndexList.Last.Value.Key);
        }
    }

    protected sealed override CacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value)
    {
        return new CacheValue(value);
    }

    protected override void CacheValueInvalidated(CacheValue cacheValue)
    {
        _IndexList.Remove(cacheValue.IndexRef);
    }

    protected override void FlushUnlocked()
    {
        base.FlushUnlocked();
        _IndexList.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, yes I was focused on keeping as much internal as possible. I guess making some implementation detail public might be an acceptable trade-off

Answer (score 2):

I'm missing [XML Documentation on these classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

---

```
public abstract class Cache<TKey, TValue>
```

You *could* short the type parameters with `K` for key and `T` for type. That's at least the "default" usage in Java, I'm not sure if that rule can be applied to C# (especially now that I see that this style is used in the framework itself, but something nice to keep in mind), too.

---

You're inconsistent with your naming, sometimes you call `TValue` `v` or`value`, on the other hand you also call `ICacheValue` `v`, `value` or `valueCache`. You should always use `value` for `TValue` and `valueCache` for `IValueCache`.

---

```
protected abstract ICacheValue CreateCacheValue(TValue value);
protected abstract void UpdateElementAccess(TKey key, ICacheValue cacheValue);
protected abstract void CacheValueInvalidated(ICacheValue cacheValue);
```

Due to the missing documentation, these names seem sub-optimal. For exampling, does `CreateCacheValue` also put the value into the cache? If yes, it should maybe be called `Put` or `Store`. What does `UpdateElementAccess`? Does it update some sort of access control within the cache for the given value? Should it only be called `Update`? `CacheValueInvalidated` should most likely be called `InvalidateCacheValue` or `Invalidate` or `Remove`.

Note that all this confusion could be cleared by documentation.

Comment: `CacheValueInvalidated` is the correct name, but `UpdateElementAccess` should probably be `ElementAccessed`. These are are called when that action happens so the derived class can perform additional housekeeping. I guess some documentation can't hurt :P